# Within-individual multivariate analysis

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I have three continuous variables that represent the wintering habitat of a species.  For most individuals, I have those three variables in two (often) consecutive years; however, for ~10-25% of the population, I have those three variables in three consecutive years.

A truncated version of my data is below.  Each individual in each year is on a separate like and A, B and C represent the three continuous habitat variables.

```
> head(bank.multi)
  species       band year    A     B      C
1    Bank 2560-01635 2014 -60.28 -26.27  8.63
2    Bank 2560-01667 2014 -46.57 -18.39  9.60
3    Bank 2560-01712 2014 -33.28 -21.80  7.87
4    Bank 2560-01713 2014 -14.64 -17.26  8.86
5    Bank 2560-01741 2014 -43.45 -20.94 10.66
6    Bank 2730-54073 2014 -42.27 -21.75 10.50
```

I'm trying to determine if the three habitat variables are the same across years for each individual.  Put another way, does each individual spend the winter in similar habitats across years?

However, I'm not sure how to get at the within-individual differences.

I've tried the following:

```
summary(manova(cbind(d2H,d13C,d15N)~band, data=bank.multi))
```

The result is significant, but I think it's just saying there are significant differences between individuals, rather than significant differences within individuals.

All thoughts appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical method to test a particular hypothesis, you should be asking on [stats.se]. If this is supposed to be a programming question, then be more specific about what you expect to happen or what method you want to use.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll put it on Cross Validated.